# Filling a 2D array in Java with for each

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sure there is something simple that I am missing here, but I have a 2d array of Coin objects called coinBox that I have initialized and I want to fill it with Coin objects using a for each loop. When I use a regular for loop it works fine but with a for each I just end up with all my Coin objects in coinBox staying null. Here is my code.

```
  for(int r = 0; r < coinBox.length;r++){
     for(int c = 0; c < coinBox[r].length;c++){
        coinBox[r][c] = new Coin(country,0,0);
     }
  }
  for(Coin[] coin : coinBox){
     for(Coin c : coin){
        c = new Coin(country,0,0);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of arrays for-each such as

```
for(Coin c : coin){ 
    //do something with `c`
}
```

is same as

```
for(int i = 0; i<coin.length; i++){
    Coin c = coin[i];
    //do something with `c`
}
```

So as you see `Coin c` is local variable which holds value from array at position `i`. So each time you do

```
c = new Coin(country,0,0);
```

you are assigning new value to that local variable `c`, which can't affect array.

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes sense.